# How to add "link boxes" to \href that disappear when printing?

Tags: hyperref

I want to:

- make `\href` more visible by adding boxes (in red or green) like the other hyperref links have.
- Ideally, I want this boxes to show up in the PDF but disappear when the PDF is printed (otherwise I can just generate two documents, one for viewing and one for printing).

EDIT:

the boxes disappear if in the following I uncomment the `colorlinks` line

```
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\hypersetup{
 %          colorlinks,
            breaklinks,
            linkcolor=darkblue,
            urlcolor=darkblue,
            anchorcolor=darkblue,
            citecolor=darkblue
           }
```

Is there a way to be able to color `\href` links while preserving the box?

Comment: If you do not have such boxes you should add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that can be used to reproduce your problem, test our suggestions and modify it to show you an answer. Without your question is somehow unclear and could be closed.

Comment: I've expanded the question.

Comment: But the example is still not a MWE but only a snippet. Please look a the link in my first comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default there is a cyan box around the `\href` link text:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href[page=2]{http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/mwe.pdf}{MWE-Manual
  Page 2}
\end{document}
```

is shown as:

[image: cyan \href link]

The cyan border is not printed. It is only visible in the PDF viewer.

`hyperref` itself does not provide colored links with borders. Option `colorlinks` always switches off the link borders. But you can try to set `pdfborder` to `0 0 1` after `hyperref` has activated colored links in `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}}}

\begin{document}
\href{http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.pdf}{hyperrref manual}
\end{document}
```

This will result in

[image]

I do not like this. It's just too much.

Comment: It depends on the PDF viewer whether the box is visible or not. On Apple PDFKit based viewers it isn't.

Comment: @egreg: Every PDF feature depends on the viewer. If a viewer does not support link boxes, use another one. The boxes are a feature usually supported by almost every viewer, e.g., Adobe Reader, okular, evince, Texstudio's internal PDF viewer, firefox's `PDF.js` …

Comment: It wasn't a critique, just a warning that the box might not appear.

Comment: @egreg But does PDFKit based viewers show the boxes for other links then (see the first item of the question)?

Comment: @Schweinebacke you are correct, I was setting `\hypersetup{colorlinks}` somewhere in my document, and that removes the box. Is there a way to color the links while preserving the box?

Comment: @gnzlbg You can (see the extended answer) but I wouldn't.